# Light affecting all objects and passing through walls in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a house scene where it has number of walls, when i add directional or spot lights the light passes through walls irrespective of the direction of light positioned.How can i make my light not to pass the wall ?

Comment: Have you set a material for your wall and set a transparency for your material  `material.transparent = false` ?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a way how the WebGL 3D rendering works. All materials will be affected by light. You can render a shadows: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/01/20/casting-shadows/
but, that means the light on the Meshes will be always rendered and after this will be rendered a shadow. That means, if you have a `meshPhong` material with a high `shininess`, it will be rendered visible and darkened by the shadow, which is not physically possible in real.
[image]